# Crystal Report without using forms and database

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a VS solution that is trying to generate a Crystal Report without using forms. To generate a report with form, the below code is used.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    cryRpt.Load(PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh(); 
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ExportOptions CrExportOptions ;
        DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
        PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf";
        CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;
        {
            CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
            CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
            CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
            CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
        }
        cryRpt.Export();
    }
```

I would like to generate a PDF without form. So there my code will go something like that

```
_crAdviceRpt.Load("C:\Users\AD_AdviceTemplate.rpt")
Dim ds As ADDataset = New ADDataset
Dim dt As ADDataset.ADDatatableDataTable = New ADDataset.ADDatatableDataTable
Dim dr As DataRow
dr = dt.NewRow
dr("strLinesList") = strLine
dt.Rows.Add(dr)
_crAdviceRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
```

However I am getting a problem as I am not so sure how to replace the following code

```
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

for non-form based method.

Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: What do you exactly mean by non-form based ? The lines of code that you wrote set ReportViewer source to the report, if you want to only export your report to PDF you don't need those lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by saying "I would like to generate a PDF without form" you want to do this using console then just write your code in `Main`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    cryRpt.Load(@"D:\daily study\console crystal\ConsoleApplication1\CrystalReport1.rpt");
    ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
    DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
    PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf";
    CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;
    {
        CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
        CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
        CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
    }
    cryRpt.Export();
}
```

Code from: [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b402d6e9-3137-4d0a-bd04-ec875c1e3e17/export-crystal-report-to-pdf-from-a-console-application?forum=vscrystalreports)

Comment: Hi syed farjad, I have tried to you your method to export however, I always have a missing parameter value exception during runtime. Are you able to advice?

Comment: Try [this](http://peoplesoft.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/peopletools-l/crystal-runtime-exception-missing-parameter-values-5158982) and let me know if it helped...

Answer (score 0):

The error shows, that your crystal report internal parameter not passed

or

**if you used sp in report , then read below point**

Crystal report sp and actual sp does not same. 
 After making this report, are you change in sp, specially to change in parameter datatype, length, rename etc.

So this effect the defination in sp, which you already refer in crystal report. While executing it always sync.

This error comes when both portion is not same.

So just go to database menu and verify that first.

**Go to the TOOLS menu and from the WIZARDS sub-menu select change data source / database**
--------------------------**---------------------------------------

Now other issue it may be you are not passing the parameter which is must from your c# code.

```
 for(int i=0;i<ReportDoc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Count; i++)
    if(ReportDoc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields[i].FormulaName==
                    "{" + paramName + "}")
    ReportDoc.DataDefinition.FormulaFields[i].Text = "\"" +paramValue +"\"";
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5492/Passing-Parameters-to-Crystal-Reports-at-Runtime

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/753879/Automatically-Setting-a-Parameter-from-a-Csharp-Va